# Dockerfile: $HOME is not working with ADD/COPY instructions

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Before filing a bug I would like to ask someone to confirm the weird `docker build` behavior I have recently faced with.

Consider we have a simple Dockerfile where we're trying to copy some files into home directory of a non-root user:

```
FROM ubuntu:utopic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN sed -i.bak 's/http:\/\/archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu\//mirror:\/\/mirrors.ubuntu.com\/mirrors.txt\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://repo.aptly.info/ squeeze main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/_aptly.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys e083a3782a194991
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y aptly

RUN useradd -m aptly
RUN echo aptly:aptly | chpasswd

USER aptly
COPY ./.aptly.conf $HOME/.aptly.conf

COPY ./public.key $HOME/public.key
COPY ./signing.key $HOME/signing.key
RUN gpg --import $HOME/public.key $HOME/signing.key

RUN aptly repo create -comment='MAILPAAS components' -distribution=utopic -component=main mailpaas
CMD ["/usr/bin/aptly", "api", "serve"]
```

That's what I get when I am trying to build this image:

```
    ...    
    Step 10 : USER aptly
     ---> Running in 8639f826420b
     ---> 3242919b2976
    Removing intermediate container 8639f826420b
    Step 11 : COPY ./.aptly.conf $HOME/.aptly.conf
     ---> bbda6e5b92df
    Removing intermediate container 1313b12ca6c6
    Step 12 : COPY ./public.key $HOME/public.key
     ---> 9a701a78d10d
    Removing intermediate container 3a6e40b8593a
    Step 13 : COPY ./signing.key $HOME/signing.key
     ---> 3d4eb847abe8
    Removing intermediate container 5ed8cf52b810
    Step 14 : RUN gpg --import $HOME/public.key $HOME/signing.key
     ---> Running in 6e481ec97f74
    gpg: directory `/home/aptly/.gnupg' created
    gpg: new configuration file `/home/aptly/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
    gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/aptly/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
    gpg: keyring `/home/aptly/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
    gpg: keyring `/home/aptly/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
    gpg: can't open `/home/aptly/public.key': No such file or directory
    gpg: can't open `/home/aptly/signing.key': No such file or directory
    gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Seems like `$HOME` is empty. But why? Putting the absolute path to home dir instead of `$HOME` is not very convenient.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. $HOME is normally set by the shell I believe and you don't have a shell inside a Dockerfile. You can always `ENV HOME /home/aptly` and then the above would work.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here's your problem:

When you use the `USER` directive, it affects the userid used to start new commands inside the container.  So, for example, if you do this:

```
FROM ubuntu:utopic
RUN useradd -m aptly
USER aptly
RUN echo $HOME
```

You get this:

```
Step 4 : RUN echo $HOME
 ---> Running in a5111bedf057
/home/aptly
```

Because the `RUN` commands starts a new shell inside a container, which is modified by the preceding `USER` directive.

When you use the `COPY` directive, you are not starting a process inside the container, and Docker has no way of knowing what (if any) environment variables would be exposed by a shell.

Your best bet is to either set `ENV HOME /home/aptly` in your Dockerfile, which will work, or stage your files into a temporary location and then:

```
RUN cp /skeleton/myfile $HOME/myfile
```

Also, remember that when you `COPY` files in they will be owned by `root`; you will need to explicitly `chown` them to the appropriate user.

Comment: Thanks for the gotcha! The separate re-definition of `ENV` saved my butt!

Answer (score 7):

Per the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user), `USER` only applies to `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`.

> The `USER` instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use when running the image and for any `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the absolute path.

Comment: Even absolute paths might be relative to the context in your docker-compose.yml if building with docker-compose

Comment: This is actually what I had to do.