# Dockerfile - Docker directive to switch home directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For the below dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:buster

RUN groupadd -r someteam --gid=1280 && useradd -r -g someteam --uid=1280 --create-home --shell /bin/bash someteam

# Update and allow for apt over HTTPS
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt update -y 
RUN apt install python3-pip -y

# switch user from 'root' to ‘someteam’ and also to the home directory that it owns 
USER someteam

RUN pwd
```

---

`USER` just change the user but not the home directory

## Edit:

```
Step 11/14 : WORKDIR $HOME
cannot normalize nothing
```

How to change home directory to `/home/someteam`?

Comment: "Home directory" isn't usually a concept in Docker.  Installing your application in `/app` is pretty common even if that's not a "normal" Linux directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change user directory using `WORKDIR` in the dockerfile, this will become the working directory. So whenever you created the container the working directory will be the one that is pass to `WORKDIR` instruction in Dockerfile.

**WORKDIR**

Dockerfile reference for the WORKDIR instruction

> For clarity and reliability, you should always use absolute paths for
>   your WORKDIR. Also, you should use WORKDIR instead of proliferating
>   instructions like RUN cd … && do-something, which are hard to read,
>   troubleshoot, and maintain.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:buster

RUN groupadd -r someteam --gid=1280 && useradd -r -g someteam --uid=1280 --create-home --shell /bin/bash someteam

# Update and allow for apt over HTTPS
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt update -y 
RUN apt install python3-pip -y

# switch user from 'root' to ‘someteam’ and also to the home directory that it owns 
USER someteam
WORKDIR /home/someteam
```

[image]

using $HOME will cause error.

> When you use the USER directive, it affects the userid used to start
>   new commands inside the container.Your best bet is to either set ENV
>   HOME /home/aptly in your Dockerfile, which will work [dockerfile-home-is-not-working-with-add-copy-instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966198/dockerfile-home-is-not-working-with-add-copy-instructions)

Comment: Can use $ `$HOME` instead of path

Comment: Yes, thats makes more sense, updating the answer.

Comment: I add the screenshot, pls double check the spelling, it should be capital or you can verify using `echo $HOME`

Comment: Sorry, I did not double-check, it's not possible pls check the link provided in answer.

Comment: What is the docker directive to change the home directory?

Comment: As mentioned in the asnwer link home is created in previous layer, so the only option is to use `WORKDIR` this is same is `cd` in linux.

Comment: Does `USER someteam` not change the user directory? in addition to user?

Comment: No, you have mentioned explicitly in dockerfile `WORKDIR /home/someteam`