# HOME environment variable is not set in derived docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am using `node:buster-slim` as my base image.

```
ARG USER=node

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential

USER $USER
WORKDIR $HOME/app

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["node"]
```

when I check the running container the `app` directory is under the root directory not in the `/home/node/app` directory. The base image has a user `node` and it has home directory. Why is not the $HOME variable is not set correctly.

What is going wrong ?

Comment: I think is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966198/dockerfile-home-is-not-working-with-add-copy-instructions

Comment: How are you executing this `Dockerfile`? CLI command?

Comment: "Home directory" isn't especially a well-defined concept in Docker.  Just using `/app` in the image root filesystem is common.  I wouldn't try to parameterize `USER` either, especially if you know it's always going to be `node` from the base image.

Comment: @NatamOliveira Thanks, that gave me more clear explanation.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you please explain more about why it is going to be `node` user always when I run the container if I don't parameterize the USER. What happens if I parameterize the USER and run the container under a different non privileged user in a host machine.

Comment: @Dez without the user switch, since the `ARG USER` will default to`node`

Comment: The Docker daemon always runs as root, and it has no idea what user launched a container.  Since the container filesystem and the host filesystem are isolated from each other there's no need for the host and container users to match.