# Running docker container non-root user permission denied

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue while running docker container as non-root user. My DockerFile is

```
.....ARG SSH_KEY

RUN mkdir root/.ssh/ &&\
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh/ &&\
    ssh-keyscan -t (url) >> root/.ssh/known_hosts &&\ 
    echo "{SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&\
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

COPY host_config root/.ssh/config

ADD ./entrypoint.sh /apps/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod -R 755 /apps/
ENTRYPOINT "./apps/entrypoint.sh"
```

entrypoint.sh file contains git commands

```
git clone ssh://repository.com
```

Docker-compose file

```
user: 5555:5555
```

host_config file

```
Host *
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile
```

When I use user option in docker-compose file it gives an error **"fatal:could not create work tree dir repository name Permission denied"**, but when I run docker container with root user it works.

When I create new directory **"example"** in DOCKERFILE and add do
*chown* that non-root user to that **"example"** folder then try git clone in that folder it gives an error **"Host key verification failed".**

Is there any way of running docker container that has script file with git commands with non-root user?

Comment: Usually I'd run that `git clone` command, from the host, _before_ I run `docker build`.  In your current setup the image doesn't actually have the application it's trying to run, but it does have ssh credentials that are very easily, let us say, extracted and reused.  Clone the repository first using the host user's ssh credentials, then `COPY` its contents into the image.

Comment: What is the error message ? When does it occur ?

Comment: @LeGEC when I try to run with non-root user  docker-compose up. it says permission denied.

Comment: That's not very descriptive. For example : if the user is not `root`, it makes sense that `mkdir root/.ssh/` (the first action of your `RUN` line) fails with `Permission denied`. Hence my question : when does it occur ? do you know what action triggers a `Permission denied` error ?

Comment: What is your workdir? Seems you are not in the /apps/. Can you add `WORKDIR /apps/` to your Dockerfile? Otherwise, you are trying to clone the repository to a folder that you don't have permission

Comment: And btw, there is a typo in your dockerfile. `ENTRYPOINT "./apps/entrpoint.sh` it is missing y in entrypoint

Comment: @LeGEC I updated the post please check

Comment: @SergioSantiago  I updated the post please check

Answer (score 0):

There are several elements which seem a bit off in the script you posted :

- `.ssh` folder is created and set up in `/root` folder (not `$HOME` or `~` or ...), which is the explicit home folder of `root` (not of "current user")
  the following should work to set it in "my home" rather than "`root`'s home" :

  ```
   cd &&
   mkdir .ssh &&
   chmod 0700 .ssh && ...
  ```
- likewise : `host_config` is copied to `root`'s home
  see suggestions here : [Dockerfile: $HOME is not working with ADD/COPY instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966198/dockerfile-home-is-not-working-with-add-copy-instructions)
- you set up the `.ssh/id_rsa` file, which would be the private key, but you do not set the publickey
- etc  ...

To debug the ssh connection from within the container : add a `RUN ssh -v repository.com` instruction (or `-vv` or `-vvv` if you need more debug info) in your Dockerfile and check the output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added non-root user set the Home to different directory and added id_rsa and config file respectively and added git clone to dockerfile but it says host key verification failed. I have my public key added to bitbucket repo.

Comment: "Host key verification failed" is a common issue : google for it

Comment: The clean way is to provision the expected host key in `.shh/known_hosts` in your container, the quick & dirty way is to run [this command](https://askubuntu.com/a/323629/18501) once when setting up your container, so that the key returned by the server is registered.