# Docker - Adding a file to Alpine root

Tags: docker, root, alpine-linux

I tried to copy a local file (a .vimrc file) to a Docker Alpine image.
Alpine's `root` directory seems to be called `~`. (which is kinda odd, since `~` is usually `home` in the Debian world) 
And the `init.vim` file needs to be in `root`/`~`.
I've tried different methods, i.e. the `COPY` command and `RUN cp ...`. 
But the ~/.config/nvim folder remains empty. 
(the mkdir commands work) 
I was able to copy into `home/.config/nvim`, but the file does not have an effect in there it needs to be in `~`. 
Is the `root` directory read only (even for root user) in `Alpine`?

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add neovim
RUN apk add neovim-doc

RUN mkdir ~/.config
RUN mkdir ~/.config/nvim

ADD init.vim ~/.config/nvim/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in alpine image `~` alias is equal to `/root` folder

but the symbol is not interprated in Dockerfile

so it will be treated as a string and it will create a subfolder in / call ~

To copy into good folder i advice you using variable `$HOME`that contain your expected value

but by default ADD and COPY don't have access to $HOME
[Dockerfile: $HOME is not working with ADD/COPY instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966198/dockerfile-home-is-not-working-with-add-copy-instructions)

one way can be to define the HOME variable you want to use

your Dockerfile will look like :

```
FROM alpine
ENV HOME /root
RUN apk add neovim
RUN apk add neovim-doc

RUN mkdir $HOME/.config
RUN mkdir $HOME/.config/nvim

COPY init.vim $HOME/.config/nvim/
```